# How to remove/change the message displayed when opening a terminal?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, terminal

Using Ubuntu 10.10 .In GUI mode when I open up a terminal, a message is displayed at top left above the prompt: `Ghost@work-Ubuntu:~$` , I would like to change it, so I would like to know in which file the message is saved in order to access it or maybe commands to remove the message.

**Edit:** When I open a terminal in gui.need to remove the message on top

```
You seem confused
Ghost@work-Ubuntu:~$
```

Comment: I cannot understand what message are you taking about. Can you report the content of the message or show a screenshot?

Comment: I have copied the display @enzotib

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The static-text part displayed before prompt is found in `/etc/motd`. ***Motd*** stands for *Message Of The Day* (see `man motd`).

Other than this, your *startup (profile) file* can execute something like the `fortune` program (which seems to be your case). To get rid of or modify it, if you use bash, edit the `.bashrc` or `.bash_profile` and find where `fortune` is executed. See `man fortune` for details.

It can also be that the text is just constructed directly in `.bashrc`, `.bash_profile` or somewhere like that.

Comment: have a look @edit, motd is not the place as i found .

Comment: Ah, right :) It is a `fortune` then... (updated)

Comment: Thanx alot it worked....bashrc

Answer (score 0):

What you saw is call a fortune cookies (do a *man fortune* for more information.) To remove the fortune, you need to go into Gnome Desktop (yes, not very intuitive.)

1. Click the Menu button and look for "Desktop Settings", launch that app
2. Select the Terminal from the left column
3. Uncheck the *show fortune cookies* checkbox